# Running AWS Firehose in lambda.js gives an undefined error

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
```

Running above code in lambda with proper roles configured, AWS returns

> errorMessage": "undefined is not a function

Anyone have an idea how can I get firehouse to load in aws-sdk?

Answer (score 4):

I opened ticket, with amazon and they verified firehouse isn't working with lambda, yet is working ec2.

They have escalated the issue to a service-team in order to support FireHose.

Comment: Is there a public link for the ticket?

Comment: workaround was to create your own package (zip) along with 'aws-sdk' node_modules and upload to lambda, rather than doing inline

Comment: It sounds like it's not fixed yet as I have the same error message when trying to get a firehose object.

Answer (score 0):

If you update aws-sdk module to version 2.3.19 you should not get an error.